# Adding coefficient of restitution for bouncing ball

Tags: python, physics

I have the following relevant code for modelling the trajectory of a racquetball inside of a box:

```
while t<20:

    if ball.pos.x>wallR.pos.x-ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.x=-1*ball.momentum.x
        varr.axis.x=-varr.axis.x

    if ball.pos.x<wallL.pos.x+ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.x=-1*ball.momentum.x
        varr.axis.x=-varr.axis.x

    if ball.pos.y>wallT.pos.y-ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.y=-1*ball.momentum.y
        varr.axis.y=-varr.axis.y

    if ball.pos.y<wallBt.pos.y+ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.y=-1*ball.momentum.y
        varr.axis.y=-varr.axis.y

    if ball.pos.z<wallB.pos.z+ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.z=-1*ball.momentum.z
        varr.axis.z=-varr.axis.z

    if ball.pos.z>wallF.pos.z-ball.radius:
        ball.momentum.z=-1*ball.momentum.z
        varr.axis.z=-varr.axis.z

    ball.momentum = ball.momentum + g*mass*dt
    ball.pos = ball.pos + ((ball.momentum)/mass)*dt
    ball.trail.append(pos=ball.pos)
    varr.pos = varr.pos + ((ball.momentum)/mass)*dt
    varr.axis = vscale*ball.momentum
    t=t+dt
```

`varr` is simply the momentum vector that stays attached to the ball.

I was wondering what I need to do to implement a coefficient of restitution in this code so that the bounce looks a bit more realistic. I have no idea where to implement it inside of the while loop. My physics teacher basically said, "Add this into your code," and I am kind of lost.

Edit: I learned that to implement to coefficient of restitution, I needed to scale my momentum whenever it bounced off of a wall by a factor whose absolute value was less than one, but I also needed to scale it in my position update function. Would anybody care enough to explain why I had to do this?

Comment: Do you know what the coefficient of restitution is supposed to do?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think it has something to do with decreasing the amount of kinetic energy that the ball has

Comment: I think the code you have shown is not the right place to add this coefficient. It has to be added to the code which handles the bounce. As far as I can tell, this code just implements an acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i have added the code that deals with the bounce. I don't think its very efficient,  but its what I have for the situation I am trying to model, which is a racquetball bouncing in a box

Comment: Ah, so now it should be quite simple: whenever the ball bounces (i.e. in any of the `if` statements) you should scale its momentum not by -1 but by a factor whose absolute value is less than 1.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so something like ball.momentum.x=-k*ball.momentum.x ? Not sure how to comment in the block code either. Im new to this site